# How do I change the image of a HTML button on mouse over etc

Tags: html, button

How do you point to various images for various button states?
Onmouseover, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### HTML

```
<button>Hello</button>
```

### CSS

```
button {
    background: url(your-image.png) no-repeat;
}

button:hover {
    background: url(your-image-hovered.png) no-repeat;
}

button:focus {
    background: url(your-image-focused.png) no-repeat;
}
```

**Note**: The `:focus` and `:hover` pseudo classes are not supported on all IE versions (on buttons at least). You can use JavaScript to emulate. Check out the events `blur()` and `focus()` (to emulate `:focus`) and `onmouseover()` and `onmouseout()` (to emulate `:hover`).

Alternatively, if you need to support a very ancient browser (quite unlikely), you can use JavaScript, but is not recommended in this day and age when CSS provides this functionality.

Comment: Argh. I was typing out this same example with the below preamble:  

-- There are a few different approaches for changing the button states. You can use events like onmouseover and onmouseout to change the button's display.

I suggest using the CSS approach -- specifically the `:hover` pseudo class. This approach uses less code and works even if Javascript is disabled in the browser *but* is not supported in IE6. --

When you beat me to the punch.

Comment: I would add the background position to the above CSS: background:url(your-image.png) top center no-repeat;

Comment: @Christopher Regarding the background position, it really depends on where he wants the image. I've left this decision at his discretion.

Comment: To avoid repeating the `no-repeat` (heh), split up `background` into `background-image` and `background-repeat` and let CSS take care of the 'duplication'.  If you add things like background position, you won't have to modify the CSS in three places, only one.

Comment: @strager Correct, but I thought I wouldn't go into CSS optimizations in this little sample.